# Creating a timestamp on a time trigger?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, scripting, timestamp-with-timezone

-Need to create a timestamp every day at 6, checking to see if a specific column has been updated. I have the time trigger running, I get the emails that it tried to run but 'script function not found: myFunction'.

- I know I need to make 'myFunction' but should I just be using a onEdit? I'm not sure how to get it to work so every day at 1 pm, it checks a specific column for an edit, then gives a timestamp in another column if it was edited.
- I tried a few times to figure out how to get the active range sorted, but I don't know if the trigger is just running 'myFunction' at the specified time, and if I just need to write code then point the trigger at it.

---

```
function createTimeDrivenTriggers() { 

ScriptApp.newTrigger('myFunction') 

.timeBased() 

.everyDays(1) 

.atHour(13) 

.create(); 

var timeZone = Session.getScriptTimeZone();

 var timestamp_format = "mm/dd/yyyy";

 var updateColName = "Updated";

 var timeStampColName = "Timestamp";

 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not use `onEdit`.  That means "run every time someone edits this sheet."

Yes, you must write `myFunction` first.  Run it and debug it manually before you attach a trigger to it.

Do not attach the trigger with `ScriptApp`.  Click on the trigger button in the script editor, which will take you to the script.google.com dashboard where you can use a trigger setup wizard to set the trigger correctly to run 'myFunction' between 1-2pm.

Comment: Gotcha. Any reason not to use the script portion of it to make the trigger? I'm curious why I was having this much trouble.

Comment: Creating the trigger by script is good once you've worked everything out and you want the script to initialize itself or set triggers based on conditions etc.  While you're still figuring it all out, it's easier to just manage the triggers manually. Based on your information, there is no benefit for you to set the trigger by script yet.

Comment: I just keep getting undefined after trying to get the active spreadsheet, and I have no idea how to attach a trigger to this bit of code at all. How do I define the source when its not actually open, and how can I get it to take the active range?

Comment: To get the best help, you should edit your question above.  You should show `myFunction`.  I recommend getting `myFunction` working perfectly, triggered manually, before you worry about attaching a trigger. There is a clock icon in the script editor toolbar when you are ready to make a trigger. But do that after you have `myFunction`.